# Retrieving public posts from Facebook using the Graph API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I've spent hours trying to read up on Facebook's Graph API and I am very confused, so apologies if this is a ridiculously easy one to answer.

I have an application written in Python, running on a server. What I want to do (as I have been successfully been able to do with Twitter using their Streaming API) *is collect all public posts that match a set of keywords that I have*.

Do I need an application key to do this successfully?

I have been messing around with https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY - this doesn't seem to multiple keywords to track...should I use a batch query as documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/)?

Thanks for any advice. I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can search multiple keywords, just separate them with a plus sign like:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=detroit+san+francisco

This will return all posts that have 3 three words in them.

Public search currently does not require an access_token so you currently don't need to create an application for this.